# Getting data from the url using python and unzipped

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

Problem: I wanted to get the data from the following url, however, I got the following error message.
I was wondering if you could guide me to fix my error. I appreciate your time!

```
import requests
import os
urls = {'1Q16':'https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/Backblaze-Hard-Drive-Data/data_Q1_2016.zip'}
if not os.path.isdir('data'):
    os.system('mkdir data')
    
for file in urls.keys():
    if not os.path.exists('data/' + file):
        os.system('mkdir ./data/' + file)
    
    print('Requesting response from: ' + urls[file])
    req = requests.get(urls[file])
    print('Writing response to: /data/' + file + '/' + file + '.zip')
    with open('data/' + file + '/' + file + '.zip', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(req.content)

    os.system('unzip ' + 'data/' + file + '/' + file + '.zip -d data/' + file + '/')
    print('Unzipping data...')
    
    os.system('rm ' + 'data/' + file + '/' + file + '.zip')
    print(file + ' complete.')
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n')
```

Error messegae

```
Requesting response from: https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/Backblaze-Hard-Drive-Data/data_Q1_2016.zip
Writing response to: /data/1Q16/1Q16.zip
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-251ee1e9c629> in <module>
      9     req = requests.get(urls[file])
     10     print('Writing response to: /data/' + file + '/' + file + '.zip')
---> 11     with open('data/' + file + '/' + file + '.zip', 'wb') as f:
     12         f.write(req.content)
     13 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/1Q16/1Q16.zip'
```

Comment: is this a linux environment?

Comment: What OS are you working on ? are you sure that the path `data/1Q16` exists ? I mean open wont create the directories if they dont exists, it can only create files in already existing directories

Comment: @Take_Care_ I thought it would create 1Q16 automatically like it created a data directory! I am using windows.

Comment: @Simpson's Paradox if you want this work this way, better check the `pathlib` module it has more advanced things like this.

Comment: @Take_Care_ It worked when I created dir manually! I am looking for something automatics!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your directory `data/<file>` is not being created and hence `open()` can not open a file since a part of path you provided does not exist. To ensure you have full compatibity while joining paths on python, you can use `os.path.join()`. For you, this would be:

```
import requests
import os
urls = {'1Q16':'https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/Backblaze-Hard-Drive-Data/data_Q1_2016.zip'}
if not os.path.isdir('data'):
    os.makedirs("data")
    
for file in urls.keys():
    if not os.path.exists('data/' + file):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join("data",file))
    
    print('Requesting response from: ' + urls[file])
    req = requests.get(urls[file])
    print('Writing response to: /data/' + file + '/' + file + '.zip')
    with open(os.path.join("data", file, file + '.zip', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(req.content)
```